# Запутался со сравнениями ключей значений map

Tags: java

Добрый день запутался с условиями сравнения в задаче, изза этого мой вывод не совпадает с ответом в задаче.

Условия задачи:

> Друзья
>
> Вводится несколько строк по два слова в каждой - имена двух друзей.
> Дружба - вещь взаимная(с двух сторон!!!). Иначе люди - не друзья.
>
> Необходимо вывести ответ в соответствии с примерами ниже - список
> друзей. Список состоит из имен людей, список выстроен в
> лексографическом порядке(по алфавиту) по возрастанию, после имени
> человека идет фраза " дружит с : ", далее следует список имен его
> друзей, выстроенный так же по возрастанию.

```
Sample Input 1:

Mike Nike
Oleg Petr
Mike Petr
Ivan Oleg

Sample Output 1:

Ivan дружит с : Oleg 
Mike дружит с : Nike Petr 
Nike дружит с : Mike 
Oleg дружит с : Ivan Petr 
Petr дружит с : Mike Oleg 

Sample Input 2:

Валентина Ольга
Аня Иван
Майкл Соня
Умберто Хулио
Иван Петр
Петр Соня
Иван Соня
Аня Соня
Валентина Соня
Умберто Соня
Хулио Соня
Василий Соня
Sample Output 2:

Аня дружит с : Иван Соня 
Валентина дружит с : Ольга Соня 
Василий дружит с : Соня 
Иван дружит с : Аня Петр Соня 
Майкл дружит с : Соня 
Ольга дружит с : Валентина 
Петр дружит с : Иван Соня 
Соня дружит с : Аня Валентина Василий Иван Майкл Петр Умберто Хулио 
Умберто дружит с : Соня Хулио 
Хулио дружит с : Соня Умберто
Sample Input 3:

Петр Иван
Иван Петр
Олег Иван
Петр Олег

Sample Output 3:

Иван дружит с : Олег Петр 
Олег дружит с : Иван Петр 
Петр дружит с : Иван Олег
```

**Мой вывод**

```
Ivan дружит с : Oleg
Mike дружит с : Nike
Nike дружит с : Mike
Oleg дружит с : Petr
Petr дружит с : Oleg
```

**Мой код**

```
       import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
        String name1;
        String name2;

        
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            String s1 = in.nextLine();
            // проверка null и на ""
            if (s1.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            String[] words = s1.split(" ");
            name1 = words[0];
            name2 = words[1];

            ArrayList<String> people = new ArrayList<String>();
            //List<String> list = new List<String>();

            //Mike Nike || Oleg Petr || Mike Petr || Ivan Oleg
            if (map.containsKey(name1)) {
                people.add(name2);
            }else
                map.put(name1, new ArrayList<String>());

            if(map.containsKey(name2)){
                people.add(name1);
            }else
                map.put(name2,new ArrayList<String>());
        }

        Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>> people = map.entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> sg : set) {
            System.out.println(sg.getKey() + " дружит с : "+map.get(sg.getKey()));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: В map значения сделайте не строками, а списками, и друзей добавляйте в эти списки (т.е. `TreeMap<String, List<String>>` вместо `TreeMap<String, String>`). У вас сейчас каждый может дружить только с одним человеком.

Comment: Исправил пишет ошибку 24:33
java: java.util.List is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Comment: Создавайте ArrayList (или другого типа список), но не List

Comment: Исправил спасибо, но с заполнением у меня проблемы с  этими сравнениями и условиями изначально запутался, пока вывод такой Ivan дружит с : []
Mike дружит с : []
Nike дружит с : []
Oleg дружит с : []
Petr дружит с : []

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, у меня получился такой код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    Map<String, Set<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        String s1 = in.nextLine();
        // проверка null и на ""
        if (s1.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        String[] words = s1.split(" ");
        String name1 = words[0];
        String name2 = words[1];

        // Если имена еще не встречались, добавляем пустые множества друзей для этих имен
        if (!map.containsKey(name1)) {
            map.put(name1, new TreeSet<>());
        }

        if (!map.containsKey(name2)) {
            map.put(name2, new TreeSet<>());
        }

        map.get(name1).add(name2); // name1 дружит с name2
        map.get(name2).add(name1); // name2 дружит с name1
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> sg : map.entrySet()) {
        String friends = String.join(" ", sg.getValue());
        System.out.println(sg.getKey() + " дружит с : " + friends);
    }
}
```

Дополнения к тому, что я писал в комментариях к вопросу: вместо списка для друзей использую `TreeSet`, чтобы список сразу получался отсортированным. Ну и перед выводом множество друзей объединяем в одну строку через пробел с помощью метода `String.join`.

Ввод-вывод:

```
Mike Nike
Oleg Petr
Mike Petr
Ivan Oleg
Ivan дружит с : Oleg
Mike дружит с : Nike Petr
Nike дружит с : Mike
Oleg дружит с : Ivan Petr
Petr дружит с : Mike Oleg
```

Comment: Извиняюсь что не дописал условие имен

Comment: Валится на вторых именах, добавил в общий код, input 2 output2 и input3 output3

Comment: все решил, проблема была for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){, заместо фор поставил while(in.hasNext()), т.е во втором инпуте друзей пришло больше, спасибо за помощь